# Possible ArduinoJson bug on ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266, json

I'm making a small IOT project using the ESP8266 in which I make 2 API calls:

1. api.openweathermap.org for weather data
2. api.timezonedb.com

The request logic is the same for both calls, the only difference being how I parse the response string. The first response is parsed fine, while the other isn't.

1. I print the String responses to Serial, they look fine.
2. Tried both Dynamic and Static buffers to no avail.
3. Making the request only to the second API, still not being parsed.
4. If I make a test and just make the response a String, char[] or char*, it parses fine.

Parsing logic [works]:

```
StaticJsonBuffer<1000> jsonBuffer;
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response);
float raw = root[String("main")][String("temp")].as<float>();
```

Parsing logic: [does not work]

```
StaticJsonBuffer<500> jsonBuffer;
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response);

String data = root[String("formatted")].as<String>();
```

The response object looks like this:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "message": "",
  "formatted": "2017-06-30 11:34:13"
}
```

Request logic:

```
String RequestAPI::performRequest(String url, char* host){
WiFiClient client;
if (!client.connect(host, port)) {
    lcd -> clearScreen();
    lcd -> drawText("Failed to connect to API", 0, 0, this -> randomUint16());
    delay(5000);
    return "";
}

char endOfHeaders[] = "\r\n\r\n";
client.print(
String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
"Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
"Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
);
// Skiping HTTP headers from the response
client.find(endOfHeaders);

unsigned long startTime = millis();
while(client.available() == 0){
    if(millis() - startTime > this -> timeout){
        lcd -> clearScreen();
        lcd -> drawText("API request failed", 0, 0, this -> randomUint16());
        delay(5000);
        return "";
    }
}

String response = "";
while(client.available()){
    response += client.readStringUntil('\r');
}
Serial.println(response);

return response;
}
```

Now I'm thinking, could the empty message be causing a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You say that the 2 responses are parsed differently, but only show one method.  Also the line  `String data = root[String("formatted")].as<String>();` doesn't look right. From the examples I think it should be `String data = String(root["formatted"]);`

Comment: @CodeGorilla Updated answer with the working parser.

Comment: @CodeGorilla Your suggestion ends up with: 'String(ArduinoJson::JsonObjectSubscript<const char*>)' is ambiguous

Comment: Strange - I was just looking at the examples, https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/blob/master/examples/JsonParserExample/JsonParserExample.ino, sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: very helpful, I'm working a similar problem. Any chance you could share your entire code? Especially more details on the section on handling the Get request timeout. unsigned long startTime = millis(); while(client.available() == 0){ if(millis() - startTime > this -> timeout){ lcd -> clearScreen(); lcd -> drawText("API request failed", 0, 0, this -> randomUint16()); delay(5000); return ""; } }

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28646)

Comment: @micromet am planning to create a repo for this, don't have the time to refactor out my hardcoded API string and passwords. The timeout handling seems pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused because of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Was not obvious as the data printed to the serial looked completely fine. Fixed with the below code:

```
client.print(
  String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.0\r\n" +
  "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
  "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
);
```

Dunno why it worked for one API but not the other though.